# How to rotate logs in ProFTPd using cronolog or rotatelogs

Tags: linux, proftpd

I will use cronolog to rotate Proftpd logs (without restarting the Proftpd)
in */etc/proftpd.conf* I wrote:

```
SystemLog                        "|cronolog  /var/log/proftpd/%Y/%m/%d/sys2.log"
```

Arter running

```
sudo proftpd
```

I have:

- `error: unable to stat() /var/log/proftpd/|cronolog  /var/log/proftpd/%Y/%m/%d: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden`
- `Fatal: SystemLog: unable to redirect logging to '/var/log/proftpd/|cronolog  /var/log/proftpd/%Y/%m/%d/sys2.log': Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden on line 16 of '/etc/proftpd.conf`

(Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden = File or directory not found)

The same error I have then instead of cronolog I use rotatelogs

any ideas?

P.S I SOULD NOT restart the ProFTP so please dont suggest the logrotate or somethink like that!

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](http://proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_SystemLog.html) :

> SystemLog -- Redirect syslogging to a file

cronolog get data from stdin.

You can do next create simple wrapper for starting proftpd and cronolog, yep in this case you must turn all output to stdout and turn off logging:

```
proftpd | cronolog...
```

Yes in documenation(cronolog) says about named pipes, but this named pipe must be present as file(see mkfifo).
 You may create with mkfifo named pipe and set for SystemLog this file.
 Then create script wrapper for read data from previously created buffer(named pipe) and redirect to stdin of cronolog.

Update:
If you use cronolog for rotate logs, you must first run cronolog before you run ProFTPd

Comment: Tanks Ivan,   I do: `mknod /var/log/proftpd/sys.fifo p`
`chmod 666 /var/log/proftpd/sys.fifo`    In proftpd.config
`SystemLog      /var/log/proftpd/sys.fifo`   and avter restart   `SystemLog: unable to redirect logging to '/var/log/proftpd/sys.fifo'
No matching device or address found on line 19 of '/etc/proftpd.conf'``

Comment: @D.Z Try use mkfifo instead mknod.
Also I think you can see in logs next string:
'/var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log': FIFO reader process must be running first
So you may start cronolog and then start proftpd.

Answer (score 0):

Many Thanks to @Ivan Gurzhiy

Solution is: "FIFO reader process must be running first " ..)))

Thanks a lot!